# Is there an easy way in eclipse to edit one version of icon and reflect the changes for all resolutions (hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi et al) at once ?

Tags: android, android-resources, android-drawable

While working on Android projects I sometimes feel the need for editing my icons to cope up with the changes in theme and or background of activity / view that is going to hold it. The way I do it currently is I first remove the icon file from all the drawable folders and then create a new icon through launcher Icon wizard. I was wondering if there is a plugin or some way in eclipse to edit the icon and reflect the same changes for all the resolutions without the need for deleting and creating from scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I researched in several forums and I dont think eclipse has any such capability as of now.